# Oracle Apex Saved changes pop-up disappear soon

Tags: oracle-apex

For any apex page with grid changes, in the processing part there is a success message option.
When we save grid changes it pops up and has a cross on top right to close it.

Is there a way so that the success message disappears on its own in like 2-3 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Create a dynamic action on page load with javascript code execution on True event and put the snippet:

```
setTimeout(function(){     $('#APEX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE').fadeOut('slow');
},2000);
```